# Continuous deployment: how to deploy new features that are affecting client and server at the same time?

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment

The server holds logic, iOS/Android App holds UI. Common case.

How do I suppose to deploy new features in this case with continuous deployment methodology?

I assume that server-side deploy looks like that:
I'm triggering new feature deployment, load balancer starts redirecting 1% of all users to the server instance with the new feature. If everything goes smoothly, then load balancer starts redirecting 10%, 30%, etc up to 100%.

The same can be done for client apps, using, say, Codepush.

So, if I'll deploy server without an app, then there will be no new features usage and therefore no problems with new deployment for sure.

So, probably I have to deploy app first and put some kind of server version checker, so if the server has api for this new feature, the UI for this feature is being shown, and if the app is connected to the wrong server, the new UI is hidden.
That's seems primitive. I need to persist socket connection to the same server to avoid hitting the wrong server, right? And what if instance/zone/region will go down and the user will be suddenly redirected to another sone/region and new server will not have the new feature api? Probably, my assumption is wrong.

So, how do I suppose to deploy new features in this case with continuous deployment methodology?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your question is more of version compatibility nature of server/client API than CD. We have a similar requirement where a server and the clients communicate and both are constantly enhanced with features. I don't know your production software architecture which might change the needs accordingly but I'll try to come up with some ideas.

I'm going to describe two cases which might apply for you.

**First case:**

The thing is easier when you do not face the situation that new client versions need to communicate with old server versions. The new server version is deployed first and old clients simply do not use the new feature, as you've already pointed out. In this situation my recommendation is to deploy the server app first and then start to roll out the new client apps. If that's possible I would do that. It applies only when the new feature doesn't force you to break the API.

**Second case:**

In the case that new client app versions need to talk to an old server app, which I would try to avoid at all costs, the new client needs some switch inside to deactivate feature e.g. B when it's talking to an old server that doesn't support this feature. An API version counter could be the solution. But it requires the client to be able to distinct between server versions. In REST you often see the `.../v1/..` inside the URL but could be solved differently as well. Hopefully the API provides some mechanism to get the version the server speaks.

We faced both cases at the same time, the protocol changed over the time including breaking changes, so we needed to implement an API version negotiation mechanism.